# Get specific data of generic span data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have field who have span like this:

```
<span data-sp-peoplepickerprocesseduser="true" id="Notificar_x0020_a_084ffd45-b361-458e-b55f-c824ba8995ec_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com_ProcessedUser0" resolveduser="true" sid="i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan">
```

I want to know how can I retrieve retrieve only value `email@mydomain.com` of each span (I can have more than one), and distinct it to no get repeated results. Regards

Comment: You should be able to do that with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your current example.

```js
$(function () {
   // get value from sid attribute
   var sid = $('span').attr('sid');
   // extract email using regex
   var matches = sid.match(/([^|]*@[^|]*)/);
   // get email
   var email = matches[0];
   
   console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-sp-peoplepickerprocesseduser="true" id="Notificar_x0020_a_084ffd45-b361-458e-b55f-c824ba8995ec_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com_ProcessedUser0" resolveduser="true" sid="i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
```

For more info:

- [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)
- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [Regular expression: capturing groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups)
- [Regular expression: excluding specific characters](https://regexone.com/lesson/excluding_characters)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result=[]; 
 //find all spans
$('span').each(function() {
   //find all attributes
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
       var this_val=this.value;
       var this_val_arr=this_val.split('|');
       $.each(this_val_arr, function() {
         var this_val_arr_more=this.split('_');
         $.each(this_val_arr_more, function() {
              if(this.indexOf('@') != -1){  //found @ in string
                      var found_str=this.toString();
                      if(result.indexOf(found_str) == -1){  //not found in result
                          result.push(found_str);
                      }
              }
         });
       });
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<span data-sp-peoplepickerprocesseduser="true" id="Notificar_x0020_a_084ffd45-b361-458e-b55f-c824ba8995ec_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com_ProcessedUser0" resolveduser="true" sid="i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
```